# Integrate custom LPD filter into CUPS

Tags: printing, cups

I've stood up a new print server and instead of using LPD we're trying to use CUPS. The old LPD server had custom filters written in C that need to be applied to the new CUPS server. The problem is that I'm not sure how that is done.

The printers.conf file has the option 'Filter' which uses Mime types. I don't know which Mime type to use if any. I understand that I'll need to include the filter script location in the ppd file for that printer and then edit the printer.conf file, but I'm uncertain how to go about that. On the old print server we would edit the printcap file, but on the new server CUPS will edit that file after any change.

```
[root@printserver cups]# cat /etc/cups/printers.conf
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v1.4.2
# Written by cupsd on 2014-08-28 11:59
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<Printer Printer1>
Info Printer1
Location 9L
MakeModel Ricoh Aficio MP C2050 PS
DeviceURI lpd://destination_server/Printer1
State Idle
StateTime 1409252319
Type 8433916
Filter application/vnd.cups-raw 0 -
Filter application/vnd.cups-postscript 0 foomatic-rip
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>



[root@printserver ppd]# grep cupsFilter Printer1.ppd

*cupsFilter: "application/vnd.cups-postscript 0 foomatic-rip"
```

OLD server printcap file:

```
Printer1:\
:ml#0:\
:mx#0:\
:sd=/var/spool/lpd/Printer1:\
:af=/var/spool/lpd/Printer1/Printer1.acct:\
:sh:\
:rm=destination_server:\
:rp=Printer1:
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, I gave up on CUPS and used LPRng instead. It's dated but it works how we want it to.